# Return value from Task freez ui

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Why this construction is freezing ui? What i am doing wrong?*                                                                                       *

Code:

```
namespace WpfApplication
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new Data();
        }
    }

    public class Data : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private double result;

        public double Result 
        { 
            get
            {
                return this.result;
            }

            set
            {
                this.result = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChaged("Result");
            }
        }

        public Data()
        {
            AsyncWork();
        }

        public void AsyncWork()
        {
            Task<double> TestTask = Task.Factory.StartNew<double>(() =>
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
                return 0.5;
            });

            result = TestTask.Result;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void RaisePropertyChaged(string info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to make something like

```
public Data()
{
    Result = AsyncWork().Result;
}

public async Task<double> AsyncWork()
{
    Task<double> TestTask = Task.Factory.StartNew<double>(() =>
    {
        Task.Delay(1);
        return 0.5;
    });

    return await TestTask;
}
```

But it also freez ui.

Comment: Because `result = TestTask.Result;` will block the calling thread (which happens to be the ui thread) for 10 seconds until it gets the result

Comment: How can i pass value to result without blocking ui?

Comment: Thanks a lot for downvote! Can you explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because result = TestTask.Result; will block the calling thread (which happens to be the ui thread) for 10 seconds until it gets the result.

You can do this without the async/await like so;

```
Task<double> TestTask = Task.Factory.StartNew<double>(() =>
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
            return 0.5;
        });
        TestTask.ContinueWith(x =>
        {
             result = x.Result;
            //do my stuff when its done

        }, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Here we are creating a continuation on the ui thread for when your task completes. Really I don't think it's best to set the datacontext like this. I would suggest having it ready to go BEFORE assigning it to the window

Answer (score 1):

Calling Task.Result is similar to wait for task to end and than get the result.
Since it's in your ctor is pretty problematic, and it makes sence that the app won't be ready till the data is.

What you should do (in my opinion) is calling a task that will set the DataContext in the end of it.

This should prevent the ui from freezing.

Answer (score 0):

> Why this construction is freezing ui?

Because [`Result` is a blocking call](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468(v=vs.110).aspx).

> How can i pass value to result without blocking ui?

A `Task<T>` is a **future**. It represents a value that you may not have yet. If you don't have it yet, then you can't do anything with it.

What you have to do is *initialize* the ViewModel into a "loading" state and then *update* it when the asynchronous data arrives. I have an [MSDN article on asynchronous data binding that helps with this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx).